# JPA begin transaction bottleneck

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm processing huge amount of entities and persisting it to DB using hibernate. I've figured out that begining transaction take a lot of time in case of huge amount of data in the table up to a minute (Whole synchronization process took 20h when fetching the data from web service took near 3h).
Is there any way to improve this method persistence logic?

```
final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
try {
    final MfBranch branch = <get data from web service>
    em.getTransaction().begin(); // bottleneck
    em.merge(branch);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    DisposableUtils.closeQuietly(em);
}
```

I would consider it reasonable to see merge or transaction commit operations to be time consuming, but why transaction begin is time consuming?

Comment: Would it be possible to reuse just one `EntityManager` rather than creating a new one each time? Perhaps inject it with Spring for example? There may be some overhead with using a new one each time that could be avoided?

Comment: Well you can put the JDBC DataSource and connection pool into autoCommit=false mode by default, that will save a couple of commands.  But maybe you should just consider going a merge on 100 'branch' at once if the time to 'get data from web service' is not the bottleneck and the database is your bottleneck.  What you may also be observing is some other issue in your system relating to SQL transactions stalling due to some other job working with a lot of data in their transaction.

Answer (score 3):

In [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/store#Batch_Store_), there will be reference for your performance problem with large data persisting in JPA.